# Accessing $scope from within a .catch function after a promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularjs-scope, firebase-authentication

I've come across a $scope issue I cant resolve.

My App uses Google Firebase API to authenticate a user by posting to the API and display a success/error message to the user afterwards by updating the $scope variable. Here is my function

```
$scope.message = "";

$scope.signin = function () {

    var auth = firebase.auth();
    auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(signinEmail, signinPassword).catch(function (error) {
        var errorCode = error.code;
        console.log("errorCode " + errorCode);
        $scope.message = "An error Alert";
});
}
```

Updated the $scope from within my signin function is working fine but accessing it within the inner catch function is not working.

So far i have tried:

1. Changing my code to use "this" instead of $scope - This seemed to cause a bigger headache because the html displays wrong when 'this' is used. (Possibly due to the fact that the app uses ng-Route) I want to either keep my app using either $scope or 'this'.
2. I've tried injecting the $scope into the function in various ways without success.
3. I tried to create a second function that can be called from within my catch block , `$scope.updateMessage(){  }`,   but this function wont call due to the fact that is it on the $scope. If use this as a regular function `var fn = updateMessage(){  }` the scope cannot be accessed.

Comment: Blind guess, try to attach the `catch` function to the current context : `.catch(...).bind(this)` ?

Comment: You are updating scope variable outside of angular context and need to tell angular to run a digest. Suggest you use `angularfire` module to make this simpler

Comment: Try $scope.$apply(function(){$scope.message = "An error Alert";})

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies

Since I was trying to update the scope variable outside of the angular context, I was able to change it by accessing the HTML element and using $apply

```
var scope = angular.element(document.getElementById('myElement')).scope();
    scope.$apply(function () {
    scope.message = errorMessage;
    });
```